# Delayed_job + sitemap:refresh

Tags: rake, sitemap, delayed-job

So im trying to get delayed_jobs to run my sitemap:refresh command from the sitemap gem. Not sure why its not showing up in my local rake jobs:work. If i run sitemap:refresh in the terminal it runs fine and delayed_jobs runs all my other rake tasks.

in sitemap_refresh.rb

```
require 'sitemap_generator/tasks'
require 'delayed_job'
require 'delayed/tasks'

module Sitemap
  class Refresh
    def perform
      `rake sitemap:refresh`
    end
  end
end
```

in my rakefile thats calling this:

```
task :sitemap => :environment do
  load 'sitemap_refresh.rb'
  puts "Refreshing Sitemap"
  Delayed::Job.enqueue Sitemap::Refresh.new
  puts "Sitemap has been refreshed"
```

end

Ive also tried replacing `rake sitemap:refresh` with `system "sitemap:refresh"` both appear to work just not in my worker from rake jobs:work.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem turns out for just needed to replace `rake sitemap:refresh` with `Rake::Task["sitemap:refresh"].execute`